# Align items with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm new using Tailwind and I have a simple text with input that consists of two rows

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy3zg1b7/8/)

Code:

```
<div>
<div
      class="text-center p-4 flex flex-col space-x-5 space-y-4 md:flex-row md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 md:justify-center"
    >
      <p class="text-center">Value:</p>
      <div class="w-40">
        <input
          v-model="model.currentValue"
          class="p-2 border-2 border-black-500 outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 w-10"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="text-center p-4 flex flex-col space-x-5 space-y-4 md:flex-row md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 md:justify-center"
    >
      <p class="text-center">Daily Value to upload:</p>
      <div class="w-40">
        <input
          v-model="model.incrementBy"
          class="p-2 border-2 border-black-500 outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 w-10"
        />
      </div>
      <button @click="update">Upload</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the two text are not vertically aligned, the same for inputs

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a45Hs.png)

How can I align text to left and center it to input? Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use CSS grid for this:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="p-4 grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-2">
  <p class="text-right my-2">Value:</p>
  <div class="text-left">
    <input v-model="model.currentValue" class="p-2 border-2 border-black-500 outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 w-10" />
  </div>
  <p class="text-right my-2">Daily Value to upload:</p>
  <div class="text-left">
    <input v-model="model.incrementBy" class="p-2 border-2 border-black-500 outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 w-10" /><button @click="update">Upload</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```